# Что нужно сделать для "Переопределения метода"

Tags: java, android

> Переопределите метод `onCreate()`, добавив вызов метода `configure()`.
>   Этот метод выполняет настройку библиотеки Yandex SpeechKit. В качестве
>   аргументов укажите контекст приложения и ваш `API-ключ`:
>
> `SpeechKit.getInstance().configure(getApplicationContext(),`"API-ключ"`);`

API-ключ у меня есть 
Напишите, пожалуйста, как должен выглядеть код после изменений

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/speechkit/mobilesdk/doc/android/2.5/quick-start/concepts/about-docpage/
ссылка на статью

Comment: Это элементарное действие при наследовании. Какой смысл задавать вопрос когда в интернете есть куча материала?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашей `Activity` переопределите метод:

```
// переопределяем
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    [...]

    // вызываем настройку библиотеки 
    SpeechKit.getInstance().configure(getApplicationContext(), "API-ключ");       
}
```